# Maven deploy failing

Tags: maven, nexus, pom.xml

I am running maven 3.0.4. I am able to successfully run clean,package,install. But when I run `mvn deploy`, I get an errror:

I am testing this small java module which has 4 projects : 1 parent P1 and 3 children C1,C2,C3. Now this parent P1 inherits from the master project M1 which is currently not uploaded in the repository. So the problem. When I try to build P1, it throws the error

```
  Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find .....:pom:1.0.0 in http://myserver.net.intra:9000
/nexus/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
reattempted until the update interval of releases has elapsed or updates are forced and 
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10
```

---

**Update :**

`mvn deploy:deploy-file` is working and uploads the JAR successfully. But `mvn deploy` gives this :

```
   Failed to execute goal on project jurisdiction-business: Could not resolve dependencies for 
project com.a.b.c.d.-business:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find om.a.b.c.d.:jar:0.0.1-20121110.071100-3 
in http://myserver.net.intra:9000/nexus/content/repositories/public-snapshots as cached in the 
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has 
elapsed or updates are forced
```

Comment: Does `mvn deploy:deploy-file` work?

Comment: Nope.. same error.. but I have done some more configuration and looks like the <artifactID> and <groupID> etc. are wrong in the POMs

Comment: Can you update the question with info from the Nexus log?

Comment: @artbristol sorry.. do not have access to the Nexus logs

Comment: @artbristol changed the question completely

Comment: Show your complete pom's of the project, cause it looks your project is wrongly configured.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just upload M1 to the repo?

Comment: sorry I did not understand "just upload M1 to the repo?"

Comment: I think that @artbristol is asking why you can't load the M1 pom.xml into the repository. The message seems clear to me - it is saying it can't find the parent pom and you have said that M1 is not in the repo.

Answer (score 3):

Normally in this situation you would have the projects checked out in a specific pattern beside each other and use the `/project/parent/relativePath` (XPath in the pom) to specify the path to the parent project when the parent is not in a repository.

Alternatively you could use an aggregator pom and build with the aggregator pom as that will allow the parent to be resolved from the reactor.

The simplest is to just run `mvn install` on M1 so that it can be resolved from the local cache.